# Fourier transform and inverse transorm

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I have to prove that for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$
$$
\check{\hat{f}}=\hat{\check{f}},
$$
where
$$
\hat{f}(\xi):=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\xi x}f(x)\mathrm{d}x
$$
and
$$\check{f}(\xi):=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^{i\xi x}f(x)\mathrm{d}x.
$$
I know that I have only to apply Fubini's thm and to make a change of variables, but I probably make some errors...

Comment: Try writing down $\check{\hat{f}}$ as two iterated integrals and then ask yourself what conditions you need on the integrand in order to be able to apply Fubini.

Comment: I don't understand... So, in your opinion I can't apply Fubini?

Comment: No, you need to apply Fubini - I'm just trying to get you to write down the relevant iterated integral, and then check that the integrand satisfies the assumptions of Fubini's theorem so that you can apply it.

Comment: @avati91; Note that, given $f\in L^{1},$ $\hat{f}$ may not be in $L^{1};$ but if you assume $f,\hat{f}\in L^{1}$ then $\hat{f}^{\vee}=f;$ by inversion formula;